# Injective module but not flat module?

Tags: injective-module, flatness

We know a projective module is a flat module.

I want to know whether an injective module can also imply that it is a flat module.

Is there any counter example?

Thank you!

Comment: It may be helpful for your intuition about these concepts to note that, when dealing with $\mathbb Z$-modules, "flat" is equivalent to "torsion-free", "injective" is equivalent to "divisible", and "projective" is equivalent to "free".  In particular, any divisible $\mathbb Z$-module with non-trivial torsion serves as a counterexample.  The answer by zipirovich uses one of the most familiar such modules. (I believe what I wrote here about $\mathbb Z$-modules also holds for modules over any principal ideal domain.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's an example from abelian groups $=$ $\mathbb{Z}$-modules: $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ is an injective $\mathbb{Z}$-module because it's a divisible abelian group, but it's not a flat $\mathbb{Z}$-module because $\require{cancel}\xcancel{\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}\mathbb{Z}=0}$ (... sorry for the mistake ...) $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}\mathbb{Q}=0$.

Comment: Do you mean $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}\mathbb{Q}=0?$

Comment: @Hao: Yes, of course! Sorry for the mistake.Of course, $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}\mathbb{Z}=\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$. But $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}\mathbb{Q}=0$. Thank you pointing this out!

Comment: It's OK. Thank you for your answer!!

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb{Z}}  \newcommand{\Q}{\mathbb{Q}} \newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}$

$\Q/\Z$ is the first example of an injective $\Z$ module.  You should think of this group as the rational numbers on the unit circle=$\R/\Z$.  Alternatively $\Q/\Z$ can be thought of as the image of $e^{2\pi i (-)}|_{\Q}$.  Every cyclic  group sits inside here and this actually characterizes the group.

$\Q/\Z$ is not an injective $\Z$-module:

$0 \to \Z \to \Z \to \Z/2 \to 0$ is an exact sequence but
$\Z \otimes_{\Z} \Q/\Z \to \Z \otimes_{\Z} \Q/\Z \to \Z/2 \otimes_{\Z} \Q/\Z$ is not.

(b/c tensoring by $\Q/\Z$ picks out the torsion in an abelian group and discards the free part.  Thus you end up with the sequence $0 \to 0 \to \Z/2$  which isn't exact)

This contradicts $\Q/\Z$ being a flat $\Z$ module.

Comment: I think $$\frac{\mathbb{Q}}{\mathbb{Z}} \otimes \mathbb{Z} $$ isn't isomorphic to 0

Answer (score -1):

Field of fraction of an integral domain always is a flat module. Take $\mathbb Q$ as a $\mathbb Z$-module. Since $\mathbb Z$ is a PID, the injective $\mathbb Z$-modules are exactly the divisible modules, then $\mathbb Q$ is a flat injective $\mathbb Z$-module.